# Sonatype/nexus3 failed start container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nexus

I tried to use sonatype/nexus3 with multiple version of the image and got the same error. I was having the same problem with the jenkins image.

How could I fix this, on creation of tmp files they doesn't get the permission of execution.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
    # Nexus
    nexus:
            container_name: nexus
            image: sonatype/nexus3:3.9.0
            volumes:
                    - "nexus_data:/nexus-data"
            ports:
                    - "8080:8081"
```

**Command apply :**

```
chown -R 200 /nexus-data
```

**Error :**

```
2019-02-20 12:46:32,259+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable - java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /nexus-data/tmp/jna-104715263/jna4132379691934707225.tmp: /nexus-data/tmp/jna-104715263/jna4132379691934707225.tmp: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted
```

**Full error :**

```
2019-02-20 12:46:32,256+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.internal.orient.DatabaseServerImpl - Failed transition: NEW -> STARTED
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.MethodInvocationAction.run(MethodInvocationAction.java:45)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.StateGuard$TransitionImpl.run(StateGuard.java:191)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.TransitionsInterceptor.invoke(TransitionsInterceptor.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback$InterceptedMethodInvocation.proceed(InterceptorStackCallback.java:77)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback.intercept(InterceptorStackCallback.java:55)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.internal.orient.DatabaseServerImpl$$EnhancerByGuice$$5ad29faf.start(<generated>)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.internal.orient.OrientBootstrap.doStart(OrientBootstrap.java:73)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.StateGuardLifecycleSupport.start(StateGuardLifecycleSupport.java:67)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.internal.orient.OrientBootstrap$$EnhancerByGuice$$221620cd.CGLIB$start$4(<generated>)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.internal.orient.OrientBootstrap$$EnhancerByGuice$$221620cd$$FastClassByGuice$$c04bff7f.invoke(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.proxy.$MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback$InterceptedMethodInvocation.proceed(InterceptorStackCallback.java:76)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.MethodInvocationAction.run(MethodInvocationAction.java:39)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.StateGuard$TransitionImpl.run(StateGuard.java:191)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.TransitionsInterceptor.invoke(TransitionsInterceptor.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback$InterceptedMethodInvocation.proceed(InterceptorStackCallback.java:77)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback.intercept(InterceptorStackCallback.java:55)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.internal.orient.OrientBootstrap$$EnhancerByGuice$$221620cd.start(<generated>)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.extender.NexusLifecycleManager.startComponent(NexusLifecycleManager.java:155)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.extender.NexusLifecycleManager.to(NexusLifecycleManager.java:95)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.extender.NexusContextListener.frameworkEvent(NexusContextListener.java:189)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1429)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /nexus-data/tmp/jna-104715263/jna4132379691934707225.tmp: /nexus-data/tmp/jna-104715263/jna4132379691934707225.tmp: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java:947)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibrary(Native.java:922)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:190)
    at com.orientechnologies.common.jna.ONative.instance(ONative.java:31)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.engine.OMemoryAndLocalPaginatedEnginesInitializer.configureDefaultDiskCacheSize(OMemoryAndLocalPaginatedEnginesInitializer.java:167)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.engine.OMemoryAndLocalPaginatedEnginesInitializer.configureDefaults(OMemoryAndLocalPaginatedEnginesInitializer.java:77)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.engine.OMemoryAndLocalPaginatedEnginesInitializer.initialize(OMemoryAndLocalPaginatedEnginesInitializer.java:62)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.engine.local.OEngineLocalPaginated.startup(OEngineLocalPaginated.java:56)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.Orient.startEngine(Orient.java:930)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.Orient.loadStorage(Orient.java:523)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.<init>(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:173)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.<init>(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:154)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OSystemDatabase.init(OSystemDatabase.java:151)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OSystemDatabase.<init>(OSystemDatabase.java:44)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.initSystemDatabase(OServer.java:1309)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.activate(OServer.java:367)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.internal.orient.DatabaseServerImpl.doStart(DatabaseServerImpl.java:186)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.StateGuardLifecycleSupport.start(StateGuardLifecycleSupport.java:67)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.MethodInvocationAction.run(MethodInvocationAction.java:39)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.StateGuard$TransitionImpl.run(StateGuard.java:191)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.TransitionsInterceptor.invoke(TransitionsInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.internal.orient.OrientBootstrap.doStart(OrientBootstrap.java:73)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.StateGuardLifecycleSupport.start(StateGuardLifecycleSupport.java:67)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.MethodInvocationAction.run(MethodInvocationAction.java:39)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.StateGuard$TransitionImpl.run(StateGuard.java:191)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.TransitionsInterceptor.invoke(TransitionsInterceptor.java:56)
    ... 6 common frames omitted
2019-02-20 12:46:32,257+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.internal.orient.OrientBootstrap - Failed transition: NEW -> STARTED
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.MethodInvocationAction.run(MethodInvocationAction.java:45)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.StateGuard$TransitionImpl.run(StateGuard.java:191)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.TransitionsInterceptor.invoke(TransitionsInterceptor.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback$InterceptedMethodInvocation.proceed(InterceptorStackCallback.java:77)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback.intercept(InterceptorStackCallback.java:55)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.internal.orient.OrientBootstrap$$EnhancerByGuice$$221620cd.start(<generated>)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.extender.NexusLifecycleManager.startComponent(NexusLifecycleManager.java:155)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.extender.NexusLifecycleManager.to(NexusLifecycleManager.java:95)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.extender.NexusContextListener.frameworkEvent(NexusContextListener.java:189)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1429)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /nexus-data/tmp/jna-104715263/jna4132379691934707225.tmp: /nexus-data/tmp/jna-104715263/jna4132379691934707225.tmp: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java:947)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibrary(Native.java:922)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:190)
    at com.orientechnologies.common.jna.ONative.instance(ONative.java:31)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.engine.OMemoryAndLocalPaginatedEnginesInitializer.configureDefaultDiskCacheSize(OMemoryAndLocalPaginatedEnginesInitializer.java:167)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.engine.OMemoryAndLocalPaginatedEnginesInitializer.configureDefaults(OMemoryAndLocalPaginatedEnginesInitializer.java:77)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.engine.OMemoryAndLocalPaginatedEnginesInitializer.initialize(OMemoryAndLocalPaginatedEnginesInitializer.java:62)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.engine.local.OEngineLocalPaginated.startup(OEngineLocalPaginated.java:56)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.Orient.startEngine(Orient.java:930)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.Orient.loadStorage(Orient.java:523)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.<init>(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:173)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.<init>(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:154)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OSystemDatabase.init(OSystemDatabase.java:151)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OSystemDatabase.<init>(OSystemDatabase.java:44)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.initSystemDatabase(OServer.java:1309)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.activate(OServer.java:367)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.internal.orient.DatabaseServerImpl.doStart(DatabaseServerImpl.java:186)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.StateGuardLifecycleSupport.start(StateGuardLifecycleSupport.java:67)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.MethodInvocationAction.run(MethodInvocationAction.java:39)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.StateGuard$TransitionImpl.run(StateGuard.java:191)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.TransitionsInterceptor.invoke(TransitionsInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.internal.orient.OrientBootstrap.doStart(OrientBootstrap.java:73)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.StateGuardLifecycleSupport.start(StateGuardLifecycleSupport.java:67)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.MethodInvocationAction.run(MethodInvocationAction.java:39)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.StateGuard$TransitionImpl.run(StateGuard.java:191)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.TransitionsInterceptor.invoke(TransitionsInterceptor.java:56)
    ... 6 common frames omitted
2019-02-20 12:46:32,259+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable - java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /nexus-data/tmp/jna-104715263/jna4132379691934707225.tmp: /nexus-data/tmp/jna-104715263/jna4132379691934707225.tmp: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted
2019-02-20 12:46:32,259+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -  at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
2019-02-20 12:46:32,259+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
2019-02-20 12:46:32,259+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)
2019-02-20 12:46:32,259+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -  at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
2019-02-20 12:46:32,259+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -  at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
2019-02-20 12:46:32,260+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -  at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java:947)
2019-02-20 12:46:32,260+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -  at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibrary(Native.java:922)
2019-02-20 12:46:32,260+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -  at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:190)
2019-02-20 12:46:32,260+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -  at com.orientechnologies.common.jna.ONative.instance(ONative.java:31)
2019-02-20 12:46:32,260+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -  at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.engine.OMemoryAndLocalPaginatedEnginesInitializer.configureDefaultDiskCacheSize(OMemoryAndLocalPaginatedEnginesInitializer.java:167)
2019-02-20 12:46:32,260+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -  at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.engine.OMemoryAndLocalPaginatedEnginesInitializer.configureDefaults(OMemoryAndLocalPaginatedEnginesInitializer.java:77)
2019-02-20 12:46:32,260+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -  at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.engine.OMemoryAndLocalPaginatedEnginesInitializer.initialize(OMemoryAndLocalPaginatedEnginesInitializer.java:62)
2019-02-20 12:46:32,260+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -  at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.engine.local.OEngineLocalPaginated.startup(OEngineLocalPaginated.java:56)
2019-02-20 12:46:32,260+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -  at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.Orient.startEngine(Orient.java:930)
2019-02-20 12:46:32,261+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -  at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.Orient.loadStorage(Orient.java:523)
2019-02-20 12:46:32,261+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -  at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.<init>(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:173)
2019-02-20 12:46:32,261+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -  at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.<init>(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:154)
2019-02-20 12:46:32,261+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -  at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OSystemDatabase.init(OSystemDatabase.java:151)
2019-02-20 12:46:32,261+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -  at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OSystemDatabase.<init>(OSystemDatabase.java:44)
2019-02-20 12:46:32,261+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -  at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.initSystemDatabase(OServer.java:1309)
2019-02-20 12:46:32,261+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -  at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.activate(OServer.java:367)
2019-02-20 12:46:32,261+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -  at org.sonatype.nexus.internal.orient.DatabaseServerImpl.doStart(DatabaseServerImpl.java:186)
2019-02-20 12:46:32,261+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -  at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.StateGuardLifecycleSupport.start(StateGuardLifecycleSupport.java:67)
2019-02-20 12:46:32,262+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -  at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.MethodInvocationAction.run(MethodInvocationAction.java:39)
2019-02-20 12:46:32,262+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -  at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.StateGuard$TransitionImpl.run(StateGuard.java:191)
2019-02-20 12:46:32,262+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -  at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.TransitionsInterceptor.invoke(TransitionsInterceptor.java:56)
2019-02-20 12:46:32,262+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -  at org.sonatype.nexus.internal.orient.OrientBootstrap.doStart(OrientBootstrap.java:73)
2019-02-20 12:46:32,262+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -  at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.StateGuardLifecycleSupport.start(StateGuardLifecycleSupport.java:67)
2019-02-20 12:46:32,262+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -  at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.MethodInvocationAction.run(MethodInvocationAction.java:39)
2019-02-20 12:46:32,262+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -  at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.StateGuard$TransitionImpl.run(StateGuard.java:191)
2019-02-20 12:46:32,262+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -  at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.TransitionsInterceptor.invoke(TransitionsInterceptor.java:56)
2019-02-20 12:46:32,263+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -  at org.sonatype.nexus.extender.NexusLifecycleManager.startComponent(NexusLifecycleManager.java:155)
2019-02-20 12:46:32,263+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -  at org.sonatype.nexus.extender.NexusLifecycleManager.to(NexusLifecycleManager.java:95)
2019-02-20 12:46:32,263+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -  at org.sonatype.nexus.extender.NexusContextListener.frameworkEvent(NexusContextListener.java:189)
2019-02-20 12:46:32,263+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -  at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1429)
2019-02-20 12:46:32,263+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -  at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
2019-02-20 12:46:32,263+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable -  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: change to  `chown -R 655 /nexus-data`

Comment: This didn't change anything, the files are created this way (and I can't change the mask)

Comment: Try: ```sudo mount /nexus-data -o remount,exec```

Comment: Can't on a container

Comment: @rseddon - Add your comment as answer! This could also happen if you move the docker volume itself to another mount point without exec enabled.

Comment: `chown -R 200:200 /nexus-data` is actually necessary instead of `-R 200`